# How to estimate the observation level data generating when there is unequal sampling of data for each record

Tags: expectation-maximization, density-estimation

I am looking at bid amounts for cars sold at a sealed auction (only the seller has all the information). I am trying to predict the number and magnitude of offers that a car will receive. Some of the cars only have one bid, but other cars are very popular and have dozens of different bids. Since the data is not i.i.d, I am not sure of the best way of moving forward. I have focused on the sales price, but it feels like I am throwing out a lot of useful information.

Are their established practices for using all the data? This seems like a something that might come up in physical sciences (multiple observations of some subjects, but not others).